# Can I make this prime Finder code more concise?

Tags: javascript, primes

I feel like I have an extra variable in there some where.

Particularly the found variable.  Is there a shorter or more efficient way to write this?

```
// 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17

function findPrimes(N){
  const primes = [2];

  for(let i = 2; i <= N; i++){
    let found = true;

    for(let j = 0; j < primes.length; j++){
      if( i % primes[j] === 0){
        found = false;
        break;
      }  
    }
    if(found){
      primes.push(i);
    }
  }
  return primes;
}

findPrimes(100);
```

Comment: There is a site for that (code review)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how verbose and literal do you want the code to be. For example, this should be the exact equivalent of your algorithm:

```js
// 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17

function findPrimes(N) {
  const primes = [2];

  for (let i = 3; i <= N; i++) {
    if (!primes.some(n => i % n === 0)) {
      primes.push(i);
    }

  }

  return primes;
}

console.log(findPrimes(100));
```

Comment: Forgot about the higher order function some.  Do you use some often?

Comment: Yes, both `some` and `every` are very useful at making the code more concise.

Comment: I remember seeing it in Undersocre.js ... odd they built that when it already exists on the prototype for Arrays.

Comment: @j.a. At the time when underscore came out, arrays didn't have these functions. And 2nd. the native functions can be painfully slow compared to, not necessarily underscore, but lodash's implementation for example.

Comment: You do not need to try even numbers, since you have already included the only even prime: 2.  Your loop can start at 3 and step through the odd numbers: 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, ...

Comment: @Thomas - why did you delete your answer it appeared to be a damn good answer especially with the performance comparison.